# globally changing beamer bullets to empty

Tags: beamer, itemize

Using the `\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]` you can change the itemize symbols to something else than the default triangle.

I wish to change the default symbol to nothing, i.e. that `\item` should behave as `\item[]`.

Unfortunately `\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[{}]` or leaving it empty puts out the default behaviour.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\begin{document}
\frame{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] item1
        \item item2
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[{}]
\begin{document}
\frame{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] item1
        \item item2
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{nothing}{}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[nothing]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[] item1
        \item item2
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I will be accepting in 4 minutes :)

Comment: @fbence though I don't know what a better answer would look like, you shouldn't accept instantly. It is better to wait an adequate amount of time and accept the best answer provided by that time.

Comment: Ok, I'll check back sometime next week then :)

Comment: Realizing that `item 1` and `item 2` aren't the real itemize text, you may want to watch out for items whose length makes them appear to blend in with the item on the next line.

Comment: @MikeRenfro I also like to add more space between items. I pretty much use itemize to be able put `[<+(0)-| alert@+(0)>]` type overlays without much typing.

Comment: @fbence put a `\itemsep=10pt` or something like that *inside* the `itemize` environment.

Comment: @fbence Alternatively to increase the spacing in every `itemize` you can use: `\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\itemizeBAK\itemize
\LetLtxMacro\enditemizeBAK\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}[1][]{\itemizeBAK[#1]\itemsep=10pt}{\enditemizeBAK}`

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry, this is a misunderstanding, I already have this covered, I was just replying to Mike Renfro, that I have the situation of multiple line items without bulletpoints merging covered :) I used an answer from tex.SX that pathces `\itemsep` in `\itemize`